# Parse JSONArray in RecyclerView from assets

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I have troubles with parsing JSON data into recyclerview, on attemp to parse it's throws NullPoilnetException like JSONArray is empty, when it's has data

Activity that shows in recyclerview parsed data in it:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class JSONSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String TAG = JSONSearchActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ArrayList<JSONSearchItem> listContentArr = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONSearchItem item = new JSONSearchItem();
    JSONSearchItemAdapter adapter;

    @BindView(R.id.jsonRecycler) RecyclerView recyclerView;

    Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new JSONSearchItemAdapter(listContentArr);
        setJSONItems();
    }
     private void setJSONItems()  {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(loadJsonEvent("asset1.json"));
                JSONArray message = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Station");

                for (int i = 0; i <= message.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject temp = message.getJSONObject(i);
                   item.setStationNAme(temp.getString("Name"));
                    item.setStationLine(temp.getString("Line"));
                    listContentArr.add(item);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter.setListContent(listContentArr);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }

        }

        //load JSON from Assets
        public String loadJsonEvent(String jsonName) {
            String json = null;
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(jsonName);
                int size = inputStream.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                inputStream.read(buffer);
                inputStream.close();
                json = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return json;
        }
    }
```

JSON file. I used [this](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) website to analyze json file and it's show it have 1 object, "station" array with items in it.So it's not null

```
        {
          "Station": [
            {
              "Name": "Station1",
              "Line": "Line1"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Station2",
              "Line": "Line3"
    ....
            }
          ]
        }
```

As i say before, when app try to starts it's go in crash with `NullPoilnetException` with next log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at 

    com.appexample.JSONSearchItemAdapter.onBindViewHolder(JSONSearchItemAdapter.java:38)
            at com.appexample.JSONSearchItemAdapter.onBindViewHolder(JSONSearchItemAdapter.java:11)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
```

...

My RecyclerViewAdapter named JSONSearchItemAdapter :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JSONSearchItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JSONSearchItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    //Creating an arraylist of POJO objects
    private ArrayList<JSONSearchItem> pad_list;
    View view;
    MyViewHolder holder;
    private Context mcontext;

    public JSONSearchItemAdapter(ArrayList<JSONSearchItem> data){
        this.pad_list = data;
    }
    //This method inflates view present in the RecyclerView
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.search_activity, parent, false);
        holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    //Binding the data using get() method of POJO object
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final JSONSearchItem list_items = pad_list.get(position);
        holder.stationName.setText(list_items.getNameStation());//logs show nullpointer error happens here
        holder.lineName.setText(list_items.getStationLine());
    }

    //Setting the arraylist
    public void setListContent(ArrayList <JSONSearchItem> pad_list) {
        this.pad_list = pad_list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pad_list.size();
    }

    //View holder class, where all view components are defined
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView stationName, lineName;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            stationName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stationView);
            lineName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lineView);
        }
    }

}
```

and POJO

```
public class JSONSearchItem {

    @SerializedName("Line")
    private String stationLine;
    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String nameStation;

    public JSONSearchItem() {

    }

    public String getStationLine() {
        return stationLine;
    }

    public void setStationLine(String stationLine) {
        this.stationLine = stationLine;
    }

    public String getNameStation() {
        return nameStation;
    }

    public void setNameStation(String nameStation) {
        this.nameStation = nameStation;
    }
}
```

I tried another aproach using combination of JSON and GSOn, but it didn't worked too

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(loadJsonEvent("asset1.json"));
            JSONArray message = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Station");
            Gson gson =new Gson();
            for (int i = 0; i <= message.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject temp =message.getJSONObject(i);
                item = gson.fromJson(temp.toString(), JSONSearchItem.class);
                listContentArr.add(item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter.setListContent(listContentArr);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

So i have a question what is wrong in my methods for parse code and how I can fix this?
Thanks in advance!

UPD:
Error where caused by this: I set for view inflation same layout as activity has, when it must be layout where single item situated

```
 view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.search_activity, parent, false);
```

Comment: Add your R.layout.search_activity too

Comment: as @Jorgesys show me, i mistakenly used layout from main activity in recyclerview inflater.
Anyway thanks for answer

Comment: It's a common mistake, it'll throw NullPointerException for a view whenever the view isn't present in your layout hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is indicated here:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

your view `holder.stationName` has null value, this is caused because the view with id `stationView` doesn´t exist in your `search_activity.xml` layout.